# MySQL Setting one row out of many as default

Tags: mysql, performance, dataset, sql-update, default

I have a table that could potentially contain millions of records. I want only one record in that table to be a **default** or **chosen** record. There can never be more than one default record. What I am currently doing is I have a column called `default TINYINT(1) UNIQUE` where non default value is `1` and everything else is `NULL`. This works fine in my limited dataset of ~100 records. Everytime I change the default, I run the following query:

```
UPDATE table SET default = NULL;
UPDATE table SET default = TRUE WHERE id = :chosen;
```

The problem I foresee is when the number of records increase substantially, I can see performance loss because of the `UPDATE` queries.

My question is, is there a better way to set a default row , while ensuring only one can exist, which would work fast regardless of the amount of rows in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Your first query does not have a where clause and mysql will go trough the entire table.

Add a `WHERE default IS NOT NULL` to it.

Also you will need to use a transaction to make sure 2 threads don't mess up while trying to change the default at the same time. If you don't, one of them might get a duplicate key error.

Answer (score 0):

why not change your column once to NULL by the dafault and not everytime you change it.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN foo SET DEFAULT NULL ;
```

and then you run an update `default` your choosen id

```
UPDATE table SET default = TRUE WHERE id = :chosen;
```

Comment: This method would require the mysql user to have the alter table permissions would it not? Also, if I only alter the table once, when I choose a default two times, the second query will run twice. But how would I remove the first default?

Comment: as i said , first alter run it once and remove it .

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to do a single, blanket update:

```
UPDATE table SET default = (id = :chosen);
```

This will set the default flag to true for the given id and false for all other records.